# First I'm the parent and then I'm the daughter

Tags: riddle, physics, chemistry

A simple, one sentence riddle which I'm confident you'll know when you have the correct answer.

*First I'm the parent, but I lose He and some energy, then become the daughter.*

What does this riddle depict?

Hints:

> The father-daughter titles are important.
>
>  Neither parent, nor daughter are compounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question suggests

> **Radioactive decay**: The "parent" nucleus, after decay, has changed into a "daughter" nucleus.  Losing energy is part of the process.  However, losing a "H" (i.e. proton) isn't one of the forms of radioactive decay.  Losing an electron, so a neutron essentially becomes a proton, is the closest.  Losing two protons and two neutrons is another, or a gamma particle could be emitted. In no case, though, is a solitary proton "lost".  Perhaps if the riddle said "but I lose an **e** and some energy" or "lose a **He** and some energy" this would fit better.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Water?

Because

> Water is H<sub>2</sub>O, and if it loses a Hydrogen atom (H) it becomes HO - a hydroxide.

I though of this because

> The puzzle is marked with the [physics](/questions/tagged/physics) and [chemistry](/questions/tagged/chemistry) tags.

Alternatively it could be

> H<sub>2</sub> and becomes H

Comment: Great answer and nice try, but it's not what i'm looking for. You're on the right track though!

Comment: @TommyWoldt is it simply H2, which goes to H? (It could really be any compound with hydrogen in it). Or is it not related to hydrogen at all?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil All I'll say for now is that your comment and answer are incorrect.